# sqlite replace() function to perform a string replace

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a column in a sqlite database that I need to modify.

The column is an array of values that looks like this:

```
0.021460.04419,0.04551,0.02734,0.011,0.005
```

The array is missing a comma between the first and second value, so the array should look like this:

```
0.02146,0.04419,0.04551,0.02734,0.011,0.005
```

The data values will never be greater then 0.9, so I am trying to build an update query that will use the replace() function to perform a string replace, identifying the second "0." and replacing it with ",0.", but I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a comma to *all* occurrences of `0.`:

```
               replace(TheColumn, '0.', ',0.')
```

then remove the duplicates:

```
       replace(replace(TheColumn, '0.', ',0.'), ',,', ',')
```

and the comma at the beginning:

```
substr(replace(replace(TheColumn, '0.', ',0.'), ',,', ','), 2)
```

Comment: It almost worked except for the leading comma, using:
UPDATE keymap SET key_json = substr(replace(replace(key_json, '0.', ',0.'), ',,', ','), 2);
I get:
"poe":",0.02731,0.05742,0.05684,0.03973,0.02187"

Comment: Works for me. `substr(...,2)` always removes one character; what is the first character without the `substr`?

Comment: Ah ok, in that case it is not working for me because I have other stuff in the record: {"latitude":83.1,"longitude":-83,"poe":",0.027310.05742,0.05684,0.03973,0.02187"}
so for me it is removing the first curly bracket: "{"

Comment: Then you can replace `",`.